# react-select cannot set id

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Have a react-select component and the id field does not get set?  Is it possible to set an id?

```
<Select
    id={field}
    className="reqform-project-dropdown"
    {...f.props(field)}
    disabled={
        readOnly ||
        onEdit ||
        f.props(field).read_only
    }
    clearable={false}
    options={this.props.common.tests}
    onChange={this.handleProjChange.bind(this, field,
        f.props(field).multiple,
        'test_req_unique_prefix')}
    labelKey="test_name"
    valueKey="test_req_unique_prefix"
/>
```

I have resorted to setting the id of the parent div, but it seems silly I can't do it directly for the select.

Comment: are you talking about [this](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) library?

Comment: You're missing the `value` prop.

Comment: What do you wanna achieve with this `id` prop?

Comment: Want the id for more reliable selenium testing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `inputProps` prop as in the docs.

If what you want is focus when clicking the corresponding label, passing `id` inside `inputProps` should work.

```
<label htmlFor={'fieldId'} />
<Select inputProps={{ id: 'fieldId' }} /> // should be an object
```

Answer (score 38):

In version >= 2 of react-select, the prop to set the id is called `inputId`. Use it like this:

```
<Select inputId="your-custom-id" />
```

Comment: Thank you @Honza Kalfus

Comment: it's helpful. Thanks

Comment: It works for CreatableSelect also - <CreatableSelect inputId="your-custom-id">

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see anything about setting an `id` attribute in their [docs](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) but you can use [ref](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to get a refference to the DOM element and add it through this object.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.select.wrapper.id = "myId";
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Select
          ref={ref => { this.select = ref; }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```