# How to add an id to react-select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I need to know when I click on a `react-select` component. So I thought by giving it an id and then handle it with `window.addEventListener`. Based on their [official guide](http://window.addEventListener), it seems that I have simply to pass id as its prop but it doesn't work.

I have this code:

```
<Select
  defaultValue={defaultValue}
  options={options}
  styles={selectStyle()}
  onFocus={onFocus}
  onChange={onChange}
  placeholder={placeholder}
  value={value}
  inputProps={{ id: labelId }}
  id="123"
/>
```

Then I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46453827/react-select-cannot-set-id/54865410) answer here, but id doesn't work.

So I tried passing `idName` and `inputProps={{ id: 'fieldId' }}` but nothing happens. I check the select id by inspecting with chrome tools and by logging it. It simply doesn't have one. Is there a way to pass an id to the component or another way to check whether I click on the select or outside?

Comment: Looking through React-Select docs, you might be looking for `instanceId` or `id`. Both should be valid props. Refer to: https://react-select.com/props#select-props Also, instead of thinking in old-school eventListeners, use the `onClick` handle, which is also an available prop according to their docs. But since I don't know why you need to know which select is clicked, I can't help you further.

Comment: @Martin I have to verify when I click outside the select as well.. with onClick I only invoke a method when I click on one specific component.. Basically I have a label, user clicks on it, label disappears and the select appears. After user selects an option OR he clicks outside then the select disappears and appears back the label.